# Does B'Twin advertise us as a source for any questions?

Tags: discussion

Man, there are a lot of questions that involve B'Twin bikes, especially as someone's first question on this site...

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty unlikely but not impossible - its probably more that btwin bikes are sold at a price point and/or retail chain that appeals to personalities who would do research on the web.

If they were more expensive, the buyer might be more likely to spend on an LBS.

If they were super cheap.... well even the web is in range of most first world citizens, from cellphones to free wifi to internet computers at the local library.

Or are you suffering from ["Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon" or "frequency illusion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153166/what-is-the-term-for-when-you-become-more-aware-of-something) ?

---

A search gets these counts for mentions of a word:

43 mongoose

46 huffy

307 cannondale

359 giant

600 specialized

650 trek

22 btwin and 28 for twin

So perhaps its not as common as you think?

Comment: It's entirely possible, just seems like there are a lot...  searching for B'Twin, I get 11 results, in the past 2 years, not to count the ones that misspell or change the name somehow...